# Pandas - Apply function and generate more than one row with lambda function

Tags: pandas

This apply function works but I don't think its efficient;

```
xyz = data.apply(lambda row: pd.Series({"z":getNVC(row)[0],"y":getNVC(row)[1],"x":getNVC(row)[2]}),axis=1)
```

So I basically want to apply the NVC function once per row and return an `np.array` which has 3 elements. I then map these 3 elements to new columns x,y and z. However, I think at the moment I am calling the function 3 times?

Ideally I would like to just call it once, save in the output in a variable, say `output` and unpack the three elements into the columns. The allocation would probably be something like;

`pd.Series({"z":output[0],"y":output[1],"x":output[2]})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going purely by creating the `dict` (that is input to `Series`), while calling `getNVC` only once, the following may work:

```
pd.Series( dict(zip("zyx", getNVC(row))) )
```